# Lucene / Solr security when OLS (Oracle Label Security) is required

Tags: java, oracle, solr, lucene

This is going to be a bit open-ended initially.  My team has a requirement to utilize Oracle Label Security (OLS).  Because we would like to enable "fast" search capabilities (Solr/Lucene) how can we correctly retrieve data that is cached (Lucene/ Solr) based on the OLS policy in place?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can use external systems like your OLS is Solr's [PostFilter interface](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/PostFilter.html). A very good write up how to do use this has been published in the article [*Custom security filtering in Solr*](http://searchhub.org/2012/02/22/custom-security-filtering-in-solr/) by Erik Hatcher.

Basically you have a hook after all search and filtering has been done. There you can open a connection to your database and filter the search results according to the user's access rights.

To speed this up, you should consider to place some security relevant artifacts into you index, which you then include as ordinary filter. That way you can do a pre-filtering, so that you do not overwhelm the PostFilter.

Currently there is nothing pre-build by the community, but you could kick-off something on GitHub.